# Detect signature of selector

Tags: objective-c

How can I check the signature of the selector, or whether the selector requires parameters or not?

E.g. I want to check whether the selector is of type 
`-(void) method` 
or
 `-(void) method:(id)param`

Comment: Note that `method` and `method:` is considered as a different selector.

Comment: I must ask; what are you trying to do?!?

Comment: I am writing a app used as a test framework.

Answer (score 8):

You can get a lot of information about a particular selector with the [`NSMethodSignature`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSMethodSignature_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class:

```
id obj = ...
SEL selector = ...

NSMethodSignature *signature = [obj methodSignatureForSelector:selector];
NSUInteger args = [signature numberOfArguments];
int i;
for(i = 0; i < args; i++)
   printf("argument type at index %d: %c", i, [signature getArgumentTypeAtIndex:i]);
```

Comment: `[[obj class] instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:selector]` can be written as `[obj methodSignatureForSelector:selector]`

Answer (score 0):

You can check this using `respondsToSelector:`, ie something like this:

```
if ( [myObject respondsToSelector:@selector(doSomethingWithOneArgument:)] ){
    ....
}
```